# Is rubbing one's penis to get out sperm permissible?

Tags: masturbation

I am a 17-year old boy, and I want to know if Islam allows one to rub one's penis to get out sperms (semen).

When I get into for bath that time I feel something different, or sexual desire, and I won't be able to stop my hand from rubbing my penis, and as a result sperm comes out, and I feel something different, but after rubbing penis I wash it from water as I am bathing. So, I wanted to know that it is good habit or bad habit related to Islam?

If it is bad habit I ask for forgiveness for Allah for that all thing!
If it is not bad then it's ok.

Comment: I was just want to know is it allowed or not, i mean YES or NO

Answer (score -1):

Its not allowed and mastrubation is also strictly  forbidden. You will have to  undergo severe torment of Allah if u do that. Be patient while feeling sex that's better for you.